# How to fix pagination to load more data from server in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to load more data from the server. I should get `firstItemId` form the item is in `RecyclerView`. In `listView` I just did it on this way.

```
listMain.setOnScrollListener( new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount != 0) {

            if (lasttotal[getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER )] != totalItemCount) {
                lasttotal[getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER )] = totalItemCount;
                lastpage[getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER )]++;

                try {

                    JSONObject js_id = new JSONObject( view.getItemAtPosition( firstVisibleItem - 2 ).toString() );

                    static_id_news = js_id.getInt( "Id" );

                    if (getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) != 0)//"page=0&tagid="

                        new ApiNews( getActivity(), (ArrayAdapter) listMain.getAdapter(), rootView, ly_dialog ).execute( "id=" + static_id_news + "&tagid=" + newsnum[getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER )] + "&page=" + scroll_last_page + 1, 2 );
                    else
                        new ApiNewsPaper( getActivity(), (ArrayAdapter) listMain.getAdapter(), rootView, ly_dialog ).execute( lastpage[getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER )] );


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now I want just like example which will take the id of `row` and send it to load more data. Thanks.

Comment: use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution for `recyclerview`

You should use `recyclerview` , its better than `listview` because its fast , less complex and customization is available like staggerd view

```
 private int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
 private boolean loading = true;

 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
            {
                visibleItemCount = gridLayoutManager1.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = gridLayoutManager1.getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = gridLayoutManager1.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (loading) {
                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                        loading = false;
                        //Do pagination.. i.e. fetch new data
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

and set loading to true in response of your `api` like in success and failure case

```
loading = true;
```

where `gridLayoutManager1` is layout manager, it could be `linearlayout` and `gridlayout` also , depends on your `recyclerview`

```
 recyclerViews.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager1);
```

Comment: thanks.. and I want get row Data in JsonObject.. I have some problem there.

Comment: can you please explain "row Data in JsonObject" so i can understand it and help you :)

Comment: just like example I used in listView .. I made a jsonObject and get data from that for Load more data

Comment: yep ... I visited the site.. but I didn't get it @pskink